# Alternative library/template class for the deprecated auto_ptr in C++17

Tags: c++, replace, auto-ptr

Have shared project library that has to be compiled with various compilers C++17 C++03 etc.  So just using the better `unique_ptr` or the less than perfect `auto_ptr` as appropriate is not ideal if the code is to be kept common.

Have look at the #ifdef type solution but it gets messy.
Plus making edits to well tried and tested coded is not a particular attractive idea!

Anyone know of a form, fit and function drop in replacement for `auto_ptr`?

Comment: One thing you could do is you could use `unique_ptr` if you have C++11 or greater, or `shared_ptr` before (even `boost::shared_ptr` if there's no `std::shared_ptr`). That would avoid the problems with `auto_ptr`

Comment: If it's only internal to the library, you could use have an #ifdef that resolves to `auto_ptr` for c++03 and `unique_ptr` for c++11 and later, and another that's blank or `std::move`, for ownership transfers. If its external you can't be sure that the user won't misuse `auto_ptr`

Comment: BTW, the OP doesn't seem interested in a solution with macros.

Answer (score 1):

There are [Boost.Move](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/move.html) and [Boost Smart Pointer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm). `std::unique_ptr` and `std::auto_ptr` may be replaced by [`boost::movelib::unique_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/move/reference.html#header.boost.move.unique_ptr_hpp). `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` by [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) and [`boost::weak_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm).

And, you can be more expressive with [`boost::scoped_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) when there is no intent to transfer ownership.